# Inline Styling for Email Template to make it like bootstrap grid from col-md-6 to col-12

Tags: html, css

Currently I want to make email template, I'm usually make my email template with each content/row, but this time I must make an email template with the template where it have 2 column in desktop and change it to 1 column in mobile, exactly like bootstrap grid if you apply it like this: `<div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>` but since I make it using media query, when I send the email, obviously the style doesn't work since you can only use inline for email template and since media query can't work in inline style, my template become break, can someone help me with this problem?

this is my css line:

```
.col-md-6 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-grow: 6;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-12 {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        flex-grow: 12;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

my goals is to make it looks like this while the email successfully sent

[image: In Desktop]

[image: In Mobile]

can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The sad reality is that support for media queries on email clients is more than limited. You can add style tags and media queries within them, but only some web-based email clients will accept them as valid, and even the ones that accept media queries might still be blocking some properties of css and may not accept newish things like flex display.